# Download and moving .apk with bash

Tags: android, macos, bash, curl, apk

I made a script to clean a ROM and install specific apps but when I look in the folder Mac is not seeing my .apk as unix exec file how can i fix this

here is part of the script:

```
getapex='curl -s -o ApexLauncher.apk apex.anddoes.com/Download.aspx'
$getapex
mv ApexLauncher.apk $currentdir/system/app/
```

hope you guys can help....

Comment: you see any error like permission denied to `mv` or any other error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not seeing the .apk file as a "unix exec file" as you say, then maybe you need to give it execution permission with:

`chmod +x ApexLauncher.apk`

Comment: can I do this in one go in the script?